# MongoDB allow access only from local server

Tags: mongodb

I am utilizing MongoDB as a database platform into my application.
As a security measure I need to allow my database to be accessible only from my server.
Looking forward for appropriate solution.

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable MongoDB access control. This uses a bindIp value in the mongod.conf file that by default listens to connections locally (e.g. bindIp:127.0.0.1 or with another local address, bindIP:127.0.0.1,10.0.0.10).

For that, you will need to create an admin or root user by doing this:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "root",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Something similar you will need to do to create a user for your application:

```
use appDatabase
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "appUser",
    pwd: "appUserPassword",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "appDatabase" } ]
  }
)
```

Then, in your mongod.conf file (in a CentOS server is located at /etc/mongod.conf), do the following:

- Uncomment 'security'.
- Add below it 'authorization: enable' (keep authentication commented out).
- Make sure the bindIp value is set to 127.0.0.1

Then, when logged onto your server, if you need to connect to your MongoDB instance, do that with the admin/root user you just created:

```
mongo -u root -p --authenticationDatabase admin
```

You should also make sure you can successfully log onto mongo with your appUser:

```
mongo -u appUser -p --authenticationDatabase appDatabase
```

From your application, you will need to connect with an URL similar to this one:

```
mongodb://appUser:appUserPassword@localhost:27017/appDatabase?authSource=appDatabase
```

Reference: 
[MongoDB - Enable Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/enable-authentication/) | 
[MongoDB - Configuration File Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/configuration-options/)

Comment: In addition to limiting network exposure with bindIP (which should be the default in packaged installs of MongoDB 2.6+) and configuring access control (which is not set up by default), I would recommend enabling the O/S firewall and reviewing other measures as per the MongoDB Security Checklist: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/.